# Clear data every night from a spreadsheet

Tags: scripting, datatrigger, eventtrigger

Teacher entered lunch count to a google spreadsheet...would like data triggered to zero every night...When teachers open next day...the count is zero
tried using the following code.gs

```
function myFunction() {
    function ClearSheet() {
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("BuelLunch");
        sheet.clearContents()
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Sorry about that    The above clears my formulas also....Would like them to be number zero...upon clearcontents

Comment: Then you will have to loop through cells and set them to 0